# Replacing multiple characters

Tags: android, string, replace

Actually in my AndroidApp im trying to do something that had to be easy but damn, it's not that i expected.
I'm trying to replace all 'td' from a string to '*space*' by doing

```
String = String2.replace('</td>',' ');
```

But it's saying me that there is too many character in character literal.

Comment: `'</td>'` should be a String literal, not a char literal. Use double quotes around it, like `"</td>"`.

Comment: damn that was easy, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
    String cat = "the cat ran across the street.";
    String replace = cat.replace("cat", "dog");
    System.out.println(replace);

    String td = "the cat </td> across the street.";
    String replacetd = td.replace("</td>", "didnt make it");
    System.out.println(replacetd);
```